# How to mount so spaces in filenames are replaced

Tags: mount, filename

I know that there are many ways to replace spaces in filenames with underscores by renaming the file.

But what I am searching for is a way to access the untouched files with a different filename (a little like [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs), but targeted at whitespace).

An example would be

```
./my bad filename
```

should show as

```
./my_bad_filename
```

It would be ok for me if the solution isn't as general as mounting, but maybe uses Samba. For the data that needs the fix, I'm using an indirect Samba mount anyway.

Thanks a lot!